# How to extend nuxt.config.js to add stylus-loader and css-loader to my nuxt application?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want to add [CSS loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) to my Nuxt.js project by adding what follows (as mentioned in the documentation link) **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I also read on the [Nuxt.js official documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/extend-webpack/) how to extend **webpack.config.js** for a Nuxt.js application by simply modifying the **nuxt.config.js** file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
     extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
       // ...
     }
  }
}
```

But when I open **nuxt.config.js**, I find this snippet in place:

```
extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        })
      }
    }
```

Given these information ( and my limited knowledge of settings this stack to which I am new),  I did this -which seems to work:

```
extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          loader: 'stylus-loader',
          loader: 'css-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        })
      }
    }
```

When I run my project: `npm run dev`, all is Ok; this is also fine when I refresh my page, but I noticed whenever I open the developments tools in Chrome and I referesh the page, I get this error:

```
nuxt:render Rendering url /material-design-icons.css.map +225ms
{ statusCode: 404,
  path: '/material-design-icons.css.map',
  message: 'This page could not be found' }
```

The problem is that I already [installed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont) what Nuxt is complaining about:

```
npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save
```

I also installed the [`css-stylus`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-loader) and [`stylus-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) using `npm`.

I want to let you know that I am importing these icon fonts in **my_project/store/index.js**:

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `nuxt.config.js` file, you're pushing new rules incorrectly. You have two rules mashed together. They should be pushed separately -- one for `.js` and `.vue` files and one for `.css` files.

```
extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
  if (isDev && isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ['css-loader', 'stylus-loader'],
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to add css and stylus loader to nuxt, because it already have them.

As for your error -> it complains about css.map not a css. Basically it cant find map file. You could disable css map and it should be gone, but its just a warning and caused by developer tools that is looking for css source map

```
  build: {
    cssSourceMap: false,
```